# How do I install a .jar Minecraft mod on a Mac with OSX Maverick?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, macos

Everywhere that I have looked the instructions were either out of date, aimed towards Windows users, or were for installing mods that were in .zip files. I have a Mac that runs OSX Maverick and I have Minecraft version 1.7.10. The mod that I want to use is "Still Hungry" and it is a .jar when downloaded. I've tried Minecraft Forge, Magic Launcher, and mcpatcher with no success. I also don't have a minecraft.jar file or a bin file so if anyone could help with this issue without having to use a minecraft.jar  file or a bin file it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As described here (http://www.mcmodder.net/still-hungry):

> Install the Forge API.
>   Run Minecraft at least once.
>   Put the mod’s .jar file in the mods folder located in your .minecraft folder.
>   For any additional info, head to our big Mod Installation Guide.
>   Ready to go! Enjoy.

On the Mac, the .minecraft directory is located in your user Library folder, which is hidden by default. You can get there by clicking Finder in the Dock, pressing `Cmd+Shift+G` and entering `~/Library/Application Support/Minecraft`